# Parse the json string : receiving from a java code

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, json

I need to send the string `s` or `json` to ajax `.done` function. Here is the servlet code that has an object `list` to be sent for an `ajax` request.

```
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Tester t = new Tester(10,"s");
    Tester t2 = new Tester(20,"g");
    LinkedList<Tester> list = new LinkedList<Tester>();
    list.add(t); list.add(t2);
    String s = gson.toJson(list);
```

I need to send the json to ajax. How could I do this? I could do :

```
out.println(s);
```

But how would I then parse the string? I need to appropriately put the json data received into the `html table`.

The current `json` output from `out.println(s)` is `[{"x":10,"y":"s"},{"x":20,"y":"g"}]`

js function that will receive json :

```
function getFeFeeds() {
$.ajax( {
    url : '',
    dataType : 'json',
    type : 'GET'
  }).done(function(message) {

  }).fail(function(message) {

  });
}}
```

Comment: There are lots of tutorials on how to create html from json requests

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over the received json and do your processing -

```
$.each(message, function(index, row) {
   console.log(row[0].x); 
   console.log(row[0].y);     
});
```

Also I would suggest set encoding so that you don't have any encoding related issues -

```
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

Comment: I didn't understand the solution. Could you explain`what` and `how` are you doing?

Comment: Since you are setting `dataType : 'json'` your message will be interpreted as json. Now you iterate over it and do your processing. If you want to know more about jQuery API refer http://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: Will the function be called each time for a _new_ row?

Comment: Yes it is kind of callback for each row.

Comment: Okay, so the `message` as an argument represents one row.

Comment: No message is the json response that you got in the ajax call. Now by above syntax we are iterating over data rows in that ajax response.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72427/discussion-between-suhail-gupta-and-aniket-thakur).